# Optional defaults for optional argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax

I want to set default values to an optional argument. In the original code, the function contains multiple arguments and is called like this, where `options` is an optional argument and can contain multiple optional parameters:

```
func(arg1, arg2, options)
```

For simplicity, I removed the first two arguments in the following example. I'm currently doing it like this:

```
function test({ a = true, b = false }: { a?: boolean, b?: boolean } = { a: true, b: false }) {
    console.log(a, b);
}

// Examples
test();                      // true, false (defaults)
test({ a: false });          // false, false
test({ b: true });           // true, true
test({ a: false, b: true }); // false, true
```

There is a lot of redundancy in the function header. **I'm looking for a way to simplify the code and remove the redundancy**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter initializer can be empty object:

```
function test({ a = true, b = false }: { a?: boolean, b?: boolean } = {}) {
    console.log(a, b);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgN6IIaIC8yATiCgDSIBGRiweANmiogL4BciueA-F9ThxGKPGCrV%20NISLHs62NgEpuAKEQbEEBGmEoAdIzgBzTHglKA3KrarVAenuIAogA88AWwAOItKtQYmFaaIaFhIY6k5FQMzKyYACYoDCCMUGhK-uhYPFyxLOzB4RqR%20ZT0TCxZgbjUXFBkrMqWxZqRDdFRKNU5%20HmV5XVdhS2lA1QdKEA)